# Python telegram bot записать в переменную код

Tags: python, telegram-bot

вопрос до боли прост но не как не могу осмыслить его после php,прошу помощи.
как бы мне по команде /gpu получить в сообщении результат

```
# GPU information
import GPUtil
from tabulate import tabulate
print("="*40, "GPU Details", "="*40)
gpus = GPUtil.getGPUs()
list_gpus = []
for gpu in gpus:
    # name of GPU
    gpu_name = gpu.name
    # get GPU temperature in Celsius
    gpu_temperature = f"{gpu.temperature} °C"
    gpu_uuid = gpu.uuid
    list_gpus.append((
        gpu_name,gpu_temperature ))
```

и вот до жути хотелось бы что бот ответил какова температура

Comment: Какую переенную и куда?

Comment: Пример `if  '/gpu' in command:
            bot.sendMessage(chat_id, "Температура"`

Comment: Из выше указанного кода я получаю                                                                            ` list_gpus.append((
        gpu_name,gpu_temperature ))`                                                                                                                                                                               бот должен ответить вот это значение gpu_temperature по команде /gpu

Comment: приведите ваш код бота (блок обработки команды /gpu)